# Visual Studio 2013 not opening automatic data source configuration wizard?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, database-connection, datasource

I am a beginner to programming in C# and Visual Studio 2013. I am following [this How to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxds9ett%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) but it is not working as described. 
I am doing this:

```
Right Click on Project in Solution Explorer -> Add -> Existing Item -> Browse to my .mdf File
```

It is written that Visual Studio opens an Automatic Data Source Configuration Wizard but it is not. I have also tried drag and drop .mdf file on Solution Explorer like described in the How to: but that is not working either. Is something wrong with my VS? How should I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this instead:

Add the Database file like described in the How to: after that do the following:

```
Project -> Add New Data Source -> You will have your Data Source Configuration Wizard.

Database -> DataSet -> New Connection -> Browse to your database file in your project folder -> Select the tables -> Finish
```

You will have your database connection set up just like the automatic connection and you will be able to get your Connection String using this:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.[Select the connection string from IntelliSense
```

Answer (score 2):

I would start here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171886%28v=vs.120%29.aspx.  The link you provided is for the .NET Framework 3.5.

One thing you'll notice in Microsoft's documentation is that there is usually a drop-down that lets you change the framework scope, so you can look at the appropriate documentation for the framework and VS version you are working within.